# Seperate css for 4th sub element in a row

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to have a separate style for each 4th element in a row.My html structure is like this

```
<main>
   <div class="a">
     <div class="container"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="a">
     <div class="container"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="a">
     <div class="container"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="a">
     <div class="container"></div>
   </div>
</main>
```

and css is

```
 .container:nth-child(4n) {
        left: -2rem !important;
    }
```

So it doesn't reflect on that 4th element.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the markup you provided, your selector will never match any of your elements as there is only one child `.container` element within each `.a` parent element. What you want to select is the `.container` child element of every 4th `.a` parent element, like so:

```
.a:nth-child(4n)>.container{
    left:-2rem;
}
```

Note that the above is identical to:

```
main>div:nth-child(4n)>.container{
    left:-2rem;
}
```

---

If you're asking wht the `left` property isn't being applied to that element then that's because you also need to give it a `position`. In this case, `relative` would probably suit your needs best.

```
.a:nth-child(4n)>.container{
    left:-2rem;
    position:relative;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also achieve the above with a single property by using the `translatex` `transform` function (although `transform` does still require [some prefixing](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)].

```
.a:nth-child(4n)>.container{
    transform:translatex(-2em);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Thanks a lot for your help. It's working great now.

Comment: You're welcome, @Raj. Which solution was it you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Since each `.container` class is surrounded by `<div>`'s, you cannot select it directly because there is only one child per `<div>`. If you want to select every element inside the `<main>`, you can do something like this:

**CSS**

```css
main .a:nth-child(4n) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
   <div class="a">
     <div class="container">Hello</div>
   </div>
   <div class="a">
     <div class="container">Hello</div>
   </div>
   <div class="a">
     <div class="container">Hello</div>
   </div>
   <div class="a">
     <div class="container">Hello</div>
   </div>
</main>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7pfs4u69/)**

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Update Css**

```
.a:nth-child(4n) {
    left: -2rem !important;
    color:red;
}
```

Further [Link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/)